# How to retrieve all contacts via the Salesforce REST API?

Tags: salesforce-rest-api

I'm writing an integration between my app and Salesforce, using the Salesforce REST api, specifically the `query` (SOQL) resource (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_query.htm).

I need to be able to sync **all** contacts from Salesforce to my app, regardless of the number (e.g., there could be 10k, 100k, etc).

But I can't find a way to do this with the salesforce API. The `query` endpoint sets a max page size of 200 and max offset of 2000.

The documentation says that the response will include a `nextRecordsUrl` if there are more results than can be returned, but I don't understand how this can be used in this case. The API (jsforce npm library) **requires** a `limit` in the query, but even if I set the limit low (say 10 records), then the response includes just those 10, and no `nextRecordsUrl` (I assume because my request of 10 records is complete), and the limit can't be set higher than 200.

Is a different resource needed to get all objects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I was using the `FIELDS(ALL)` function so that I don't have to explicitly list all of the fields in the SOQL query. The requirement to include a `limit` in the query is due to the use of this function:

https://newstechnologystuff.com/soql-fields-function/

If I specify field names explicitly, then there is no requirement to include a `limit`, and then, if the number of matching rows is greater than the batch size (default 2000), I get a `nextRecordsUrl` as expected.